# How to organise login process to the scenarios of cucumberjs?

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I want to write a smoke test with cucumberjs. I'm very new to cucumber, not sure how to write scenarios for a complex process.

The process I want to check:

1. I'm an unsigned user
2. I open '/my-home' in the browser
3. It will redirect to '/login?continue=/my-home'
4. There will be a login form on the page
5. I input my username and password, and press 'login' button
6. If logged in, it will redirect to '/my-home'
7. I can see my name 'Freewind' on the page

I'm not sure how many scenarios do I need to create, one for all, or two (one for login page redirection, another for login), or more?

If I write one, it might be:

```
Scenario: Login to my home
  Given I'm an unsigned user
    And I open '/my-home' in the browser
    And it will redirect to '/login?continue=/my-home'
    And there will be a login form on the page
   When I input my username and password
    And press 'login' button
   Then it will redirect to '/my-home'
    And I can see my name 'Freewind' on the page
```

If I write two, it might be:

```
Scenario: Login page redirection
  Given I'm an unsigned user
   When I open '/my-home' in the browser
   Then it will redirect to '/login?continue=/my-home'
    And there will be a login form on the page

Scenario: Login to my home
  Given I opened the login url '/login?continue=/my-home'
   When I input my username and password
    And press 'login' button
   Then it will redirect to '/my-home'
    And I can see my name 'Freewind' on the page
```

Which one makes more sense? And is there any better way?

And I found `Given I opened the login url '/login?continue=/my-home'` is not fluent, is there any better way to express it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't write your scenarios like this. All this detail about 'how' you login belongs in code 'below' the scenarios (step definitions and helper methods). Although it might seem a little odd at first, the way to write this feature is something like

```
Feature: Registered users can login

Background:
  Given I am registered

Scenario: I log in
  When I login
  I should be logged in
```

After that you can write other scenarios like

```
Scenario: I log in with the wrong password
```

and then you can write features about unregistered users and registration

When you write features think like a business person, not a developer or tester. Explain what you want to do and why its important, leave out 'how' things are done.